Microsoft Remote Desktop client in android clipboard option missing
So i'm trying to get copy/paste between the android RD Client app and Windows working, and contrary to most answers on the internet I cannot even see a clipboard option.
For example here it's clearly visible:
https://howto.hyonix.com/article/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-copy-paste/

In my case (RD Client 8.1.81.435) I've got only this:

Does anyone have or had a working clipboard between android and windows?

The clients in those two screenshots are not identical. They are unlikely to even be the same client, given the differences in options.

You should update your app. The version of Remote Desktop you are using (Remote Desktop 8) has not been updated since 2021. You should install this Remote Desktop. As you can see, from the image shown below, Clipboard option is present in Device & Audio Redirection category.

